# 68k register addresses

Tags: assembly, machine-code, instruction-set, 68000

This question is begging for a bunch of "why are you doing this?" responses.

I haven't been able to find this information in the [68k Programmer's Reference Manual](http://www.freescale.com/files/archives/doc/ref_manual/M68000PRM.pdf), but that may be because I'm not sure of what verbiage to search for.

Here is the instruction format for the 68k's `ADD` opcode.

[image]

Bits 0-2 and 9-11 designate registers.  What are the binary representations of the 68k's registers?  Are they "addresses"?

Yes, I am aware that I can write a 68k assembly program and debug it to find this information.  I'm looking for a reference.  Thanks!

Comment: Registers don't have addresses. If you don't understand that, you don't understand machine architectures. The bits simply say which register within the CPU are to be used. They are decoded my the microcode engine.

Comment: I know they aren't memory addresses.  That's obvious.  They could still have been /called/ addresses.  Also, I didn't claim to understand machine architectures.  I'm trying to learn; pardon me for asking a question.

Comment: @mwcz we could call them "zoinks", but that doesn't make them zoinks. Terminology is important, and in the case of writing and understanding machine code programs, very important.

Comment: That's exactly why I asked the question "Are they 'addresses'?"  They could have 'register addresses' for all I know.  Don't bash someone for asking for clarification on terminology, then tell them knowing terminology is important.

Comment: Just to position myself in-between you two: in RISC architectures (which the 68000 can be seen as a forerunner to) there is the concept of "register files" and in that respect the three register bits can viewed as an index into the register file. However, the "file" resides inside the CPU itself so in my view this only complicates the meaning of the word "file" making assembly programming terminology unneccessarily ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks for breaking up the fight, Olaf. ;)  And thanks for sharing that cool bit of history.  I hadn't heard the term 'register file' before.  Terminology is important!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See Sec. 2.1, "Instruction Format":

> An instruction specifies the function to be performed with an operation code and defines the location of every operand. Instructions specify an operand location by **register specification, the instruction’s register field holds the register’s number**; by effective address, the instruction’s effective address field contains addressing mode information; or by implicit reference, the definition of the instruction implies the use of specific registers. (emphasis added)

Comment: Thanks, that helps.  I just figured it out, and it was so obvious that it's no wonder it wasn't listed in the docs. :)

Comment: @mwcz for us mere mortals following this question is the register number a 3 digit binary representation of the eight D0-D7 or A0-D7 registers?

Comment: @Caltor Yeah, it is.  When I posted this question, I was confused about how all sixteen registers (the A and the D registers) could be referenced by a 3-bit field.  It feels like a silly question now, since it's kind of obvious (in retrospect) that the number (0-7) is contained in the register field, and the addressing mode determines if that number refers to an A or D register.

Comment: @mwcz Ah the addressing mode determines whether it's an A or D register; I was missing that part. I don't think there is such a thing as a silly question. I found it useful in my understanding of 68k anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

These probably refer to the An and Dn registers listed in figure 1-1, page 1-2 of the manual you linked.

Answer (score 1):

The 3 bits specify the address register number, from 0 (bits: 0-0-0) to 7 (bits: 1-1-1). But generally you can let the assembler worry about this stuff.
I hope this helps,
Dave

Comment: Thanks.  I was writing an emulator at the time, so relying on an assembler wasn't an option.